# how to have hd button of self hosted jwplayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I have a self hosted jwplayer 7.7.1 and i want to have an HD Button in the Player
MY Code is:

```html
<div id='container'></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('container').setup({
        // URL to the video file
        file: 'https://cldup.com/EkDGt7dE43.mp4',

  skin: {
    name: "saiyans-watch"
    }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sources block with links to multiple conversions of the video. If you have additional configuration options, put them in .setup(

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("videoelement");
playerInstance.setup({      
playlist: [{
    sources: [{ 
        file: "linktolowquality.mp4"
    },{
        file: "linktohighquality.mp4"
    }]
}],
image: "i.ytimg.com/vi/TSXl_BzUysk/maxresdefault.jpg",
});
```

I have found it helpful to read their support site and developer site as it has code examples.